# Lightest hardware accelerated desktop system

Tags: x11, hardware, desktop-environment, lightweight

I need a list of **lightweight** desktop environment that uses **hardware acceleration** either natively or from being on top of another library like `Xlib`, `GTK+`, etc.

What I'm actually looking for is a replacement for the `Openbox Desktop System` that comes with my CrunchBang Linux. The distro is light enough, but it irks me that moving around the windows and interacting with all the widgets are noticeably slower than my old Windows 7 installation.

I know there are different systems out there with one being lighter on `CPU` overall or another having a better GPU acceleration support (maybe not from itself, but from better library it sits on top on). Hence my request above for a list of choices.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but I think hardware acceleration does not depend on the desktop environment. What video card are you using? Maybe you didn't install the necessary drivers.